# Philosophically motivated risk metrics

Tags: probability-theory, utility, risk-assessment

During a random process over a sample space $\Omega$, an agent incurs a cost (say, in money) given by a random variable $Z:\Omega \rightarrow R$, which is determined by the agent's action. The agent chooses the action which minimizes its "risk", which it calculates as some function $\rho(Z)$. Examples:

- A *risk-neutral* agent uses $\rho=E$, the expectation operator, to minimize expected cost.
- A *minimax agent* uses $\rho(Z)=\inf_\omega Z(\omega)$ to minimize the maximum possible cost.
- A *maxipok* agent uses $\rho(Z)=P(Z > z)$ to minimize the chance of a cost exceeding a threshold $z$.

The latter two agents are *risk-averse*: given two cost distributions with the same mean, they will associate more risk with whichever has higher variance. Risk-aversion is often quite sensible: would you rather certainly keep your house, or bet it against a second house on a fair coinflip? But expected utility theorists typically justify risk-aversion on the basis that an agent's true utility function is usually concave in their net worth--money has *decreasing marginal utility*. Equivalently, cost in utility is convex in monetary cost.

If this is the rationale for risk-aversion, then a risk-averse agent's risk metric should satisfy $\rho(Z)=E(f \circ Z)$, where $f:R \rightarrow R$ is a convex function that relates cost in money to cost in utility. It's not hard to show that the maxipok metric satisfies this relationship for $f(c) = I(c > z)$, but minimax does not for any $f$. Nor do many of the other most popular risk metrics in finance: none of the VaR$_\alpha$, CVaR$_\alpha$, and mean-variance metrics can be interpreted as minimizing the expectation of a latent disutility function. The only well-studied risk-averse metric besides maxipok with this property is entropic risk, which has $f(c) = e^{-ac}$.

**Ok, here's the question:** I'm curious whether there is a pleasant characterization of the set of risk metrics which compute the expectation of some disutility. In other words, when does $\rho:R^\Omega \rightarrow R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$ satisfy $\rho(Z) = E(f \circ Z)$ for some $f:R \rightarrow R$? Furthermore, if $f$ exists, when does it have nice properties, e.g. monotonicity, continuity, convexity?

The $|\Omega| < \infty$ case is probably the place to start, to make the measure theory less horrifying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now have a condition which I believe is necessary and sufficient in the special case of a finite sample space. My attempted proof is below.

**Claim**

*Let $\Omega = [n]$, equipped with probability $Q=(q_1,\ldots,q_n)$ in the probability simplex in $R^n$. For a given risk metric $\rho:R^n \rightarrow R$, a latent disutility function $f:R \rightarrow R$ exists satisfying $\rho(Z)=E(f \circ Z)$ if and only if for every $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subseteq R$, $${\scr Q{\bf f}=R},$$ where $\scr Q$ is an $\underbrace{n \times \cdots \times n}_\text{$n+1$ times}$ tensor, ${\bf f} \in R^n$, and $\scr R$ is an $\underbrace{n \times \cdots \times n}_\text{$n$ times}$ tensor, with the components
$${\scr q}_{\omega_1 \ldots \omega_n k}=\sum_j q_j I(\omega_j=k)$$
$${\bf f}_\omega = \rho(x_\omega, \ldots, x_\omega)$$
$${\scr r}_{\omega_1 \ldots \omega_n}=\rho(x_{\omega_1}, \ldots, x_{\omega_n}).$$.*

**Proof**

$(\implies)$ Assume such an $f$ exists. A cost variable $Z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ is an element of $R^n$, and $E(Z) =\sum_j q_j z_j$. If $Z$ is constant, then $z_j = c$ for each $j \in [n]$, and thus $$E(f \circ Z) =\sum_j q_jf(z_j)= \sum_j q_jf(c)=f(c).$$
Hence $f(c) = \rho(c,\ldots,c)$ for each $c \in R$.

For any $\{x_1, \ldots, x_n\} \subseteq R$, there are $n^n$ random variables supported on the $x_i$, each of which has the form $Z = (x_{\omega_1}, \ldots, x_{\omega_n})$. Each such $Z$ places a linear constraint on $\rho$: $$\rho(x_{\omega_1}, \ldots, x_{\omega_n})=\rho(Z)=E(f \circ Z)=\sum_j q_jf(x_{\omega_j})=\sum_j q_j\rho(x_{\omega_j}, \ldots, x_{\omega_j}).$$ The equation ${\scr Q{\bf f}=R}$ expresses all of these constraints in tensor form, so it must hold.

$(\impliedby)$ From above, $f:R \rightarrow R$ defined by $f(c) = \rho(c,\ldots,c)$ has the desired property. This completes the proof.

**Discussion**

This result allows one to easily *reject* risk functions which do not have associated latent disutilities, by evaluating $\rho$ for particular $Z$ and enforcing linear constraints. It also provides an explicit construction of the unique $f$ from $\rho$ in cases where such an $f$ exists. This makes it easy to check monotonicity/continuity/convexity.

Unfortunately, even though the condition I present is sufficient, it would be quite difficult to use this result to *confirm* risk functions which do have associated latent disutilities. I'd love to see if someone who knows more about crazy linear algebra could find a more easily verifiable sufficient condition. And of course, a generalization to infinite sample spaces would be incredible, although at this point I'm afraid I wouldn't understand it without a PhD in real analysis.